# Scala cats.Random

Tags: scala, scala-3, cats-effect

I'm trying to learn functional random from cats. This is method inside big class:

```
def prepareDate(order: Model, zoneId: String): F[Instant] =
    Random[F].betweenLong(7200, 21600).flatMap { seconds =>
      order.dateTime
        .plusSeconds(seconds)
        .toInstant(ZoneOffset.of(zoneId))
        .asInstanceOf[F[Instant]]
    }
```

it not compiles with `No given instance of type cats.effect.std.Random[F] was found for parameter ev of method apply in object Random.` error

I've tried to put Random inside this way:

```
class SomeClass[F[_]: Async: Logger: Random]
```

but have no idea how to implicit it in object-companion.

Comment: Could you please provide a full code snippet?

Comment: My personal advice is that `Radom` should not be passed nor used as a typeclass, ask for it as a normal parameter and pass it as a normal parameter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's remove some of the fluff, since the logic itself is irrelevant for the problem:

```
def prepareDate(): F[Long] =
  Random[F].betweenLong(7200, 21600)
```

So... What's `F[_]`? Compiler will ask you the same question.

If you had some concrete instance of `F[_]`, for example `cats.IO`, then the whole thing would be simple. You would just need to obtain an instance of `Random[IO]` to work with, which can be done with e.g. `Random.scalaUtilRandom[IO]` (this gives an `IO[Random[IO]]` hence the `flatMap`):

```
def prepareDate(): IO[Long] = {
  Random.scalaUtilRandom[IO].flatMap(_.betweenLong(7200, 21600))
}
```

So what your question really comes down to is - given that you don't know what the user of `prepareDate` will be using as `F[_]` (it could be `IO` or something else), how do you intend to prove that there will be a `Random[F]` available in scope?

Your `F[_]` is probably a generic parameter in the context where your `prepareDate` method is defined. In case it's a class, then what you wrote would be correct - `class SomeClass[F[_]: Random]` means that `F` has to be a higher-kinded type (due to `[_]`) and there has to be a `Random[F]` available in scope. Whoever is instantiating a concrete instance of `SomeClass` with some concrete `F[_]` will have to make sure that `Random[F]` is in scope.

Here's some complete code:

```
import cats.effect.{ExitCode, IO, IOApp}
import cats.effect.std.Random

object Main extends IOApp {

  class MyDate[F[_]: Random] {
    def prepareDate(): F[Long] =
      Random[F].betweenLong(7200, 21600)

  }

  def run(args: List[String]): IO[ExitCode] = {
    Random.scalaUtilRandom[IO].flatMap { implicit random =>
      val myDate = new MyDate[IO]
      myDate.prepareDate().flatMap(IO.println).as(ExitCode.Success)
    }
  }

  // prints e.g. 17656
}
```

You mentioned having a companion object, but that doesn't change much in the concept itself - you just move "I need some `F[_]` that has a `Random[F]` in scope" from your class definition, to your method definition:

```
object MyDate {
  def prepareDate[F[_]: Random](): F[Long] =
    Random[F].betweenLong(7200, 21600)
}

def run(args: List[String]): IO[ExitCode] = {
  Random.scalaUtilRandom[IO].flatMap { implicit random =>
    MyDate.prepareDate()(random).flatMap(IO.println).as(ExitCode.Success)
  }
}
```

Btw in case it helps you or someone else: `[F[_] : Random]` is just syntactic sugar for the implicit parameter of type `[Random[F]]`. This works equally fine, it's just more verbose:

```
def prepareDate[F[_]]()(implicit random: Random[F]): F[Long] = ...
```